# Python Array append vectors and then sum the elements of the array positionwise (not elementwise)

Tags: arrays, list, python-2.7, numpy

first of all I explain what I would like to do. I have a function which gives me some lists. These lists have the same number of elements and they contain numbers, which represents positions on the x-axis. For example one of them is `[-11, -6, -5, -4, -1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7]`, another one is `[-11, -6, -5, -3, -1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7]`. The entries will always be integers and in ascending order.

I want to run this function many times and at the end "sum-up" all these vectors in a particular way. Imagine that each vector shows the position of a person in the x-axis. I want to know, at the end of say q experiments, how many people there are in each position. However, they do not all start from -11 or end at 7.

For example `[-13, -8, -3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7]` or `[-12, -7, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]` are other two valid output from the function.

How can I do that?

My idea was to create a loop, compute the function, and store these lists into an array and then use some weird matrix operation. However I am absolutely stuck, this is my attempt, where `rep_assign_time2(n,p,m)` is the function that gives me the lists:

```
def many_experiments(n,p,m,q):
    jj = 0
    vector_min = []
    vector_max = []
    a = np.array([])
    while jj < q:
        s = rep_assign_time2(n,p,m)
        a = np.concatenate((a,s), axis = 0)      # I add s as an element of a

    for k in range(a.shape):
        ma = max(a[k])
        mi = min(a[k])
        vector_min.append(mi)
        vector_max.append(ma)
    minimum = min(vector_min)
    maximum = max(vector_max)
```

And then I have NO  IDEA on how to create an operation that does what I want. I've been thinking for an hour and still no clue. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in luck with NumPy, as there's a built-in for it as [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html). It gives us both such unique labels (axis positions in this case) and their counts at each such label. So, let's say you have the lists stored as a list, thus a list of lists as `A`, you could simply do -

```
unq,counts = np.unique(A,return_counts=True)
```

Sample run -

```
In [33]: A = [[-11, -6, -5, -4, -1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7], \
    ...:      [-11, -6, -5, -3, -1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7],\
    ...:      [-13, -8, -3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7],\
    ...:      [-12, -7, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

In [34]: unq,counts = np.unique(A,return_counts=True)

In [35]: unq
Out[35]: 
array([-13, -12, -11,  -8,  -7,  -6,  -5,  -4,  -3,  -2,  -1,   0,   1,
         2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7])

In [36]: counts
Out[36]: array([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3])

In [40]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [41]: # Plot the results
    ...: plt.bar(unq, counts, align='center')
    ...: plt.grid()
    ...: plt.show()
    ...:
```

[image]

Comment: So basically unq gives me a list where the elements are all and only the elements in A, repeated only once. And then counts gives me the "frequence" of each of them?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Yup! You got it, frequency/counts, its the same. Added a plot to make a bit more sense.

Comment: thanks a lot, I also have to make a barplot at the end, so thanks! ahah
Last thing, is there a way to append lists as elements to an array? I mean instead of just smashing them together

Comment: Not sure what you mean by appending, but see if `np.concatenate(A)` does what you intend to achieve? Or if you have them as lists `L0`, `L1`, etc. you could do : `np.hstack((L0,L1))` or `np.vstack((L0,L1))` and so on to get a NumPy array.

Comment: kind of, but with a difference. Imagine the normal list in python say `a = []` . Then if you do `a.append(3)`, you'll add an element in the last position. I want to do the same, with an array, however, each element will be a list, not a number. So that if I take element 0 from the array, I'll get the first list and so on